# Consume WCF service with wsHttpBinding using web reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-wshttpbinding

WCF service is running with `wsHttpBinding`. Is it possible to consume this service using web reference not service reference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **No** - the "old" web reference *only* works with `basicHttpBinding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`web reference` is the old-style, deprecated ASP.NET webservices (`ASMX`) technology (using only the XmlSerializer)

You cannot consume service exposed on `wsHttpBinding` with default configuration by old `ASMX`. Default configuration of `wsHttpBinding` uses advanced security and `ASMX` doesn't support it.

You must either `add service reference` / `svcutil` or change your binding to `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply